# VMware services not triggered on by starting the application

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, windows-services

I have VMware Station 10 installed on Windows 10 64 bit. I am setting all the VMware services to Manual as I want to speed up my system bootup. I was expecting when I start VMware itself, the services should be triggered on, as what "manual" usually mean.

However, the services do not start when I start VMware software. I had to manually turn them on.

Also I tried set the services as Automatic (delayed), which does not turn on after 2 min after bootup.

Can someone help me with understanding how services in Windows are handled and figure this problem out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, manual means you start them on your own. I do this via cmd script:

```
@echo off
net start VMUSBArbService
net start VMAuthdService
net start VMnetDHCP
net start "VMware NAT Service"
```